# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails when updating a foreign key

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity Member

```
public class Member implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = true)
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String password;
    private String phone;
    private String url_image;

    // posts the user has made
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();

    // load the roles everytime we load a user
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    // foreign key relationships
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "member", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<Likes> like;
    
    // constructor, getters, setters
    
}
```

an entity Role

```
public class Role {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

}
```

and an entity Post:

```
public class Post implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String text;
    private Date date;
    private String post_name;
    private String post_surname;
}
```

The entity Member has OneToMany relationships with Post and Roles and I want when an email of a member gets updated, the corresponding records on the other entities to have the updated foreign key as well. Also, there is another situation with an entity called Likes:

```
public class Likes implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Post post_id;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "email", referencedColumnName = "email")
    private Member member;

}
```

where the relationship is mapped by the Member to the Likes.
In all the situations where I am running an update query on MyQSL I get the error

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails(`members`.`member_posts`, CONSTRAINT `FKbd5r2qwucjyiwbv538j3edjad` FOREIGN KEY (`member_email`) REFERENCES `member` (`email`))
```

either coming from the member_posts table that is made from the relationship of Member and Post, or the member_roles table that is made from the relationship of Member and Roles or the Likes table. Anyone knows what I am messing up here, because I can't really figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, you've used the user's email address as the foreign key reference from the child table to the parent. Now you need to update the email address.

Foreign keys are a data integrity constraint. They exist to ensure that the child rows always have a valid reference to the parent. Thus, you can't change the parent column because the child column will no longer have a valid reference, and you can't change the child column because it will then point to a non-existent parent

(It would be possible to set the child email address to an existing but incorrect parent email, so to counter that set a UNIQUE index on the parent and update the parent table first. The parent update will then fail because of the duplicate.)

Fortunately, you can work around all this by disabling the foreign key constraints while you perform the update:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

Of course, once the update has been completed you need to enable the checks again:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

**But what if something goes wrong?**

If the update fails for some reason and foreign key checks are disabled you can leave your database in an unknown state. To cover this, wrap the entire update in a transaction:

In pseudo-code:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE parentTable set email = 'newEmail@example.com' where email = 'oldEmail@example.com';
UPDATE childTable set email = 'newEmail@example.com' where email = 'oldEmail@example.com';

IF (No error hos occurred)
    COMMIT
ELSE
    ROLLBACK
ENDIF

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

That's the MySQL solution. Using mutable data as a foreign key constraint is probably a poor choice. I'd consider replacing the email foreign key with a column that holds the parent ID and set the foreign key constraint on that. That should not change, and the email address can then be updated at will.

Unfortunately, Spring is not my thing. This is the solution, but you'll have to implement this yourself.

Comment: Doesn't mySQL provide the cascade type if you are changing a foreign key though? With ON UPDATE CASCADE and ON DELETE CASCADE. Isn't it something that can be used in this case?

Comment: @stefnto You're quite right. I wondered why I didn't think of that, but thinking back I've never set up a foreign key on mutable data so it's never been an issue.